# If function appending loading message more than once

Tags: java, android, if-statement, count

I have a loading screen, I want to display the loadingMessage1 for 3 secs than shows loading message 2. I only want loading message 2 to appear once, but when I tried to do it, loading message 2 kept getting appended in an endless loop.

So i tried put a count variable to increases after every loading message 2 append, but it doesnt work. where am i going wrong, is there another solution to this?

```
final TextView loadingMessage1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.loadingMessage1);
int count = 0;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

if (count == 0){
    handler.post(new Runnable(){    
            @Override
            public void run(){
                loadingMessage1.append("Loading Message 2");
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3*1000L);
            }   
    }); 
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake on the following line:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 3*1000L);
```

Here you send to this `Runnable` object to the handler while handling `this`. That means when you fist execute the `Runnable`, on the end you add it again to the handler's message loop. Thus you obtained an infinite loop. Something of the like will solve your problem:

```
final TextView loadingMessage1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.loadingMessage1);
int count = 0;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){    
        @Override
        public void run(){
            loadingMessage1.append("Loading Message 2");
        }   
}, 3*1000L);
```

### EDIT:

To make all this stuff flexible, do the following:

```
// inner class
class TextChanger implements Runnable {
    private final String message;

    public TextChanger(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadingMessage1.append(message);
    }

}
```

and then somewhere in your code:

```
public static final long TIME_CONSTANT = 3*1000L;

final TextView loadingMessage1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.loadingMessage1);
int count = 0;
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new TextChanger("Whatever 1"), TIME_CONSTANT);
handler.postDelayed(new TextChanger("Whatever 2"), 2 * TIME_CONSTANT);
```

and so on. The trick is not to reference `this` as you did before, because it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: what if i then wanted to add a 3rd loading message?

Comment: This already has a "3rd", including the one you've put in the `loadingMessage1` field to start with.  But to add another, just add another line like `handler.postDelayed(new TextChanger("Whatever 3"), 3 * TIME_CONSTANT);`...

Comment: Right. I assumed that there is already a "Whatever 0" the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid posting another event after each execution.  Perhaps something more like this:

```
void showMessage1() {
    // ... code to show message 1 ...

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){    
        @Override
        public void run(){
            showMessage2();
        }   
    }, 3*1000L); 
}

void showMessage2() {
    // ... code to show message 2 ... 
}
```

Note that message-showing code only executes once per message.